Accelerometer as an external Interrupt with MSP430
I am trying to put MSP430FR6889 in sleep mode and wake it up using an external Accelerometer (BMI160). Whenever someone moves the Accel, MSP430 should wake up and read the accel to process the data.
BMI 160: https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bmi160-ds000.pdf
I have so far tried to read accelerometer and process data but interrupt and waking up is not working.
Edited code:
//Accel Interrupt
#include "driverlib.h"
#include <gpio.h>
#include <intrinsics.h>
#include <msp430fr5xx_6xxgeneric.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <msp430.h>

#define ACCEL_THRESHOLD 4000
volatile int16_t accelValue = 0;

//Address if the BMI160
#define SLAVE_ADDR 0x69
//Maximum I2C buffer size
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 20

//Number of FFT samples
#define SAMPLES 10
//#define TimeStampSample 10
#pragma PERSISTENT(input)
int16_t input[SAMPLES] = {0}; //Store samples
volatile uint32_t cycleCount;

#define UP              0x0010                          // Timer_A Up mode
#define CONTINUOUS      0x0020                          // Timer_A Continuous mode
#define ACLK            0x0100                          // Timer_A SMCLK source
#define DEVELOPMENT     0x5A80                          // Stop the watchdog timer
#define BOUNCE_DELAY    0xA000                          // Delay for Button Bounce
#define MS_10           100                             // Approximate value to count for 10ms
#define SMCLK           0x0200                          // Timer_A SMCLK source
void timer_init(void)
{
    TA0CCTL0 = CCIE; //Enable counter interrupt
    TA0CCR0 = 0; //Initially stop Timer by starting at 0
    TA0CTL = TASSEL__SMCLK | MC__UP | ID__8; //Set clock source to ACLK, the count mode to Continuous, and the clock divider to 8
    TA0EX0 = TAIDEX_7; //Set expansion clock divider to 8

    TA1CCTL0 = CCIE;                          // TACCR0 interrupt enabled
    TA1CCR0 = 0;                              // Set count target to 0 by default
    // Set timer clock speed to 4.5898 ticks/s, or 16524 ticks/hour
    TA1CTL = TASSEL__ACLK | MC__STOP | ID__8; //Set clock source to ACLK, the count mode to Continuous, and the clock divider to 8
    TA1EX0 = TAIDEX_7; //Set expansion clock divider to 8
}
int delay(int count)
{
    if(TA1CTL & TAIFG)                                  // If Timer_1 is done counting
    {
        count = count-1;                                        // Decrement count
        TA1CTL = TA1CTL & (~TAIFG);                             // Reset Timer_1
    }
    return count;                                       // Return the value of count
}
void UART_transmitString( char *pStr ) //Transmits a string over UART0
{
    while( *pStr )
    {
        while(!(UCA0IFG&UCTXIFG));
        UCA0TXBUF = *pStr;
        pStr++;
    }
}
typedef enum I2C_ModeEnum{
    IDLE_MODE,
    NACK_MODE,
    TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE,
    RX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE,
    TX_DATA_MODE,
    RX_DATA_MODE,
    SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE,
    SWITHC_TO_TX_MODE,
    TIMEOUT_MODE
} I2C_Mode;

I2C_Mode MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;

uint8_t TransmitRegAddr = 0; //Register address for transmission
uint8_t ReceiveBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0}; //Buffer for received values
uint8_t RXByteCtr = 0; //Count received bytes
uint8_t ReceiveIndex = 0; //Index of received data
uint8_t TransmitBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0}; //Buffer for transmitted values
uint8_t TXByteCtr = 0; //Count transmitted bytes
uint8_t TransmitIndex = 0; //Index of transmitted data

void CopyArray(uint8_t *source, uint8_t *dest, uint8_t count)
{
    uint8_t copyIndex = 0;
    for (copyIndex=0; copyIndex<count; copyIndex++)
    {
        dest[copyIndex]=source[copyIndex];
    }
}

I2C_Mode I2C_Master_ReadReg(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t count)
{
    //printf("R\n");
    /* Initialize state machine */
    MasterMode = TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE;
    TransmitRegAddr = reg_addr;
    RXByteCtr = count;
    TXByteCtr = 0;
    ReceiveIndex = 0;
    TransmitIndex = 0;

    /* Initialize slave address and interrupts */
    UCB1I2CSA = dev_addr;
    UCB1IFG &= ~(UCTXIFG + UCRXIFG);       // Clear any pending interrupts
    UCB1IE &= ~UCRXIE;                       // Disable RX interrupt
    UCB1IE |= UCTXIE;                        // Enable TX interrupt

    UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;             // I2C TX, start condition
    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);              // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts
 //   UCB1IE &= ~UCRXIE;                       // Disable RX interrupt


    return MasterMode;

}

I2C_Mode I2C_Master_WriteReg(uint8_t dev_addr, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data, uint8_t count)
{
    /* Initialize state machine */
    MasterMode = TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE;
    TransmitRegAddr = reg_addr;

    //Copy register data to TransmitBuffer
    CopyArray(reg_data, TransmitBuffer, count);

    TXByteCtr = count;
    RXByteCtr = 0;
    ReceiveIndex = 0;
    TransmitIndex = 0;

    /* Initialize slave address and interrupts */
    UCB1I2CSA = dev_addr;
    UCB1IFG &= ~(UCTXIFG + UCRXIFG);       // Clear any pending interrupts
    UCB1IE &= ~UCRXIE;                       // Disable RX interrupt
    UCB1IE |= UCTXIE;                        // Enable TX interrupt

    UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;             // I2C TX, start condition
    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits + GIE);              // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts
    //printf("W\n");
    return MasterMode;
}

//******************************************************************************
// BMI160 Functions ************************************************************
//******************************************************************************
void bmi160_init(char FOC_axis)
{
    uint8_t writeData[1];
    //Read Chip ID, which is D1
    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x00, 1);
    if(ReceiveBuffer[0] != 0xD1)
    {
        UART_transmitString(" Incorrect sensor chip ID ");
        printf("Incorrect sensor chip ID\n");
    }




    //Configure the accelerometer
    writeData[0]=0b00101000; //Set acc_us to 0 for off, and acc_bwp must then be 010. Set acc_odr to 1011(800Hz),1100(1600Hz),1000(100Hz),0001(25/32Hz)
    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x40, writeData, 1);
    //Check if configuration worked
    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x40, 1);
    if(ReceiveBuffer[0] != writeData[0])
    {
        UART_transmitString(" Accelerometer config failed ");
        printf("Accelerometer config failed\n");
    }
    //Set the range of the accelerometer
    writeData[0]=0b1000; //0b0011 for 2g, 0b0101 for 4g, 0b1000 for 8g
    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x41, writeData, 1);
    //Check if range is set
    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x41, 1);
    if(ReceiveBuffer[0] != writeData[0])
    {
        UART_transmitString(" Accelerometer range set failed ");
        printf("Accelerometer range set failed\n");
    }


    //Set the Accelerometer to normal power mode
    writeData[0] = 0x11;
    I2C_Master_WriteReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x7E, writeData, 1);
    //Read power mode status of sensors
    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x03, 1);
    if(ReceiveBuffer[0] != 0x10)
    {
        UART_transmitString(" Accelerometer not on ");
        printf("Accelerometer not on\n");
    }

}

void initGPIO()
{
    // I2C pins (P4.0 is SDA, P4.1 is SCL)
    P4SEL1 |= BIT0 | BIT1;
    P4SEL0 &= ~(BIT0 | BIT1);

    // Configure P3.4 and P3.5 to UART (Primary, TX and RX respectively) for NeoCortec
    P3SEL0 |= BIT4 | BIT5;                    // USCI_A1 UART operation
    P3SEL1 &= ~(BIT4 | BIT5);                 // SEL1 is 0 and SEL0 is 1 for primary operation, inverse for secondary

    // Configure P2.0 and P2.1 to UART (Primary, TX and RX respectively) for PC
    P2SEL0 |= BIT0 | BIT1;                    // USCI_A0 UART operation
    P2SEL1 &= ~(BIT0 | BIT1);                 // SEL1 is 0 and SEL0 is 1 for primary operation, inverse for secondary

    // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
    // previously configured port settings
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;
    __bis_SR_register(GIE);
}

void initClockTo16MHz()
{
    FRCTL0 = FRCTLPW | NWAITS_1;

    // Clock System Setup
    CSCTL0_H = CSKEY_H;                     // Unlock CS registers
    CSCTL1 = DCOFSEL_0;                     // Set DCO to 1MHz

    // Set SMCLK = MCLK = DCO, ACLK = VLOCLK (9.4kHz)
    CSCTL2 = SELA__VLOCLK | SELS__DCOCLK | SELM__DCOCLK;

    // Per Device Errata set divider to 4 before changing frequency to
    // prevent out of spec operation from overshoot transient
    CSCTL3 = DIVA__4 | DIVS__4 | DIVM__4;   // Set all corresponding clk sources to divide by 4 for errata
    CSCTL1 = DCOFSEL_4 | DCORSEL;           // Set DCO to 16MHz

    // Delay by ~10us to let DCO settle. 60 cycles = 20 cycles buffer + (10us / (1/4MHz))
    __delay_cycles(60);
    CSCTL3 = DIVA__32 | DIVS__1 | DIVM__1;  // Set ACLK to 239.75Hz, SMCLK to 16MHz, and MCLK to 16MHz
    CSCTL0_H = 0;                           // Lock CS registers
}

void initI2C()
{
    UCB1CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                      // Enable SW reset
    UCB1CTLW0 |= UCMODE_3 | UCMST | UCSSEL__SMCLK | UCSYNC; // I2C master mode, SMCLK
    UCB1BRW = 160;                            // fSCL = ACLK/160 = ~100kHz
    UCB1I2CSA = SLAVE_ADDR;                   // Slave Address
    UCB1CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Clear SW reset, resume operation
    UCB1IE |= UCNACKIE;
}

void UART_init(void)
{
    // Configure USCI_A1 for UART mode
    UCA1CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                      // Put eUSCI in reset
    UCA1CTLW0 |= UCSSEL__SMCLK;               // CLK = SMCLK
    UCA1BR0 = 8;                              // Clock prescaler set to 8
    UCA1BR1 = 0x00;                           // High byte empty, low byte is 8
    UCA1MCTLW |= UCOS16 | UCBRF_10 | 0xF700;  // Over-sampling on, first modulation register set to 10, second modulation register set to 0xF7 (247) for high byte, 0 for low byte
    UCA1CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Initialize eUSCI
    UCA1IE |= UCRXIE;                         // Enable USCI_A1 RX interrupt

    // Configure USCI_A0 for UART mode
    UCA0CTLW0 = UCSWRST;                      // Put eUSCI in reset
    UCA0CTLW0 |= UCSSEL__SMCLK;               // CLK = SMCLK
    UCA0BR0 = 8;                              // Clock prescaler set to 8
    UCA0BR1 = 0x00;                           // High byte empty, low byte is 8
    UCA0MCTLW |= UCOS16 | UCBRF_10 | 0xF700;  // Over-sampling on, first modulation register set to 10, second modulation register set to 0xF7 (247) for high byte, 0 for low byte
    UCA0CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                    // Initialize eUSCI
    UCA0IE |= UCRXIE;                         // Enable USCI_A0 RX interrupt
}
void goToSleep(void)
{
    // Enable global interrupts
    __bis_SR_register(GIE);
    // Put MSP430 into LPM3 mode
    __bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits);
    // After waking up, the program continues from here
}

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW;   // Stop watchdog timer
    //Initialize all peripherals
    initClockTo16MHz();
    initGPIO();
    UART_init();
    initI2C();
    timer_init();
    bmi160_init('Z');
    TA0CTL   = TA0CTL | (SMCLK + CONTINUOUS);           // SMCLK:  Counts faster than ACLK
    TA0CCTL0 = CCIE;                                    // Timer_0 interrupt
    TA1CTL   = TA1CTL | (ACLK  + UP         );          // Count up from 0 with ACLK
    TA1CCR0  = MS_10;                                   // Duration approximatley 10ms
    //_BIS_SR(GIE);
    __bis_SR_register(GIE);
    int i=0;
    // Activate all interrupts
    while(1)
    {       goToSleep();
            if (accelValue > ACCEL_THRESHOLD)
                    {
                        // Display accelerometer value
                        printf("Accelerometer value: %d\n", accelValue);
                    }

          /*
           printf("Reading samples\n");
           //Read SAMPLES amount of data from the BMI160
           for(i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++)
           {
               I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x16, 2); //Read the acceleration value from the BMI160 registers
               input[i]= ReceiveBuffer[0] | (ReceiveBuffer[1] << 8); //Store the value in an array
               printf("%d\n", (unsigned)(input[i]));
                     }
           */

    }
}

 //I2C Interrupt
 #pragma vector = USCI_B1_VECTOR
 __interrupt void USCI_B1_ISR(void)
 {
   //Must read from UCB1RXBUF
   uint8_t rx_val = 0;
   switch(__even_in_range(UCB1IV, USCI_I2C_UCBIT9IFG))
   {
     case USCI_NONE:          break;         // Vector 0: No interrupts
     case USCI_I2C_UCALIFG:   break;         // Vector 2: ALIFG
     case USCI_I2C_UCNACKIFG:                // Vector 4: NACKIFG
       UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT;                 // Re-send start if NACK
       break;
     case USCI_I2C_UCSTTIFG:  break;         // Vector 6: STTIFG
     case USCI_I2C_UCSTPIFG:  break;         // Vector 8: STPIFG
     case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG3:  break;         // Vector 10: RXIFG3
     case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG3:  break;         // Vector 12: TXIFG3
     case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG2:  break;         // Vector 14: RXIFG2
     case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG2:  break;         // Vector 16: TXIFG2
     case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG1:  break;         // Vector 18: RXIFG1
     case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG1:  break;         // Vector 20: TXIFG1
     case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG0:                 // Vector 22: RXIFG0
         rx_val = UCB1RXBUF;
         if (RXByteCtr)
         {
           ReceiveBuffer[ReceiveIndex++] = rx_val;
           RXByteCtr--;
         }

         if (RXByteCtr == 1)
         {
           UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;
         }
         else if (RXByteCtr == 0)
         {
           UCB1IE &= ~UCRXIE;
           MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;
           __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0
         }
         break;
     case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG0:                 // Vector 24: TXIFG0
         switch (MasterMode)
         {
           case TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE:
               UCB1TXBUF = TransmitRegAddr;
               if (RXByteCtr)
                   MasterMode = SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE;   // Need to start receiving now
               else
                   MasterMode = TX_DATA_MODE;        // Continue to transmision with the data in Transmit Buffer
               break;

           case SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE:
               UCB1IE |= UCRXIE;              // Enable RX interrupt
               UCB1IE &= ~UCTXIE;             // Disable TX interrupt
               UCB1CTLW0 &= ~UCTR;            // Switch to receiver
               MasterMode = RX_DATA_MODE;    // State state is to receive data
               UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT;          // Send repeated start
               if (RXByteCtr == 1)
               {
                   //Must send stop since this is the N-1 byte
                   while((UCB1CTLW0 & UCTXSTT));
                   UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;      // Send stop condition
               }
               break;

           case TX_DATA_MODE:
               if (TXByteCtr)
               {
                   UCB1TXBUF = TransmitBuffer[TransmitIndex++];
                   TXByteCtr--;
               }
               else
               {
                   //Done with transmission
                   UCB1CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;     // Send stop condition
                   MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;
                   UCB1IE &= ~UCTXIE;                       // disable TX interrupt
                   __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF);      // Exit LPM0
               }
               break;

           default:
               __no_operation();
               break;
         }
         break;
     default: break;
   }
 }



#pragma vector = TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A0_ISR(void)
{
    // Read accelerometer value
    I2C_Master_ReadReg(SLAVE_ADDR, 0x16, 2);
    accelValue = ReceiveBuffer[0] | (ReceiveBuffer[1] << 8);
    printf("Interrupt value: %d\n", accelValue);
    // Wake up the MSP430
    __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM3_bits);
}



Would you mind to reduce your program to a [mre], please? -- What kind of signals does your accelerometer produce if it is moved? Only signals output without MCU triggers are interesting. -- While you're [edit]ing your question, please add a link to the data sheet of your accelerometer.

I don't see where you enable the interrupt input on the MCU or the interrupt output on the accelerometer.  Aren't you going to have to write something to the INT_MOTION registers (at least) in the accelerometer?

@kkrambo I have edited the code an removed all the unnecessary functions from the code. Whenever I run this code, my code stuck at Line 275 (__bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits); ) and does not move to further breakpoints even if its moved.
